# Changing Background Moving Speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, sprite-kit

In the gameScene background moving horizontally it's working fine but i want to move background slow and fast according to score increasing, i proceed this way with nstimeinterval changing but nothing i can see change the background moving slow and fast its just going normal, if this way is wrong someone help me please.

```
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"background10"];

    NSTimeInterval _move;
       int _gameScore;
    if (_gameScore>=5) {
        _move =0.09;
    }else{
        _move = 0.02;
    }

    SKAction *movBg = [SKAction moveByX:-backgroundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:_move*backgroundTexture.size.width]; 
    SKAction *resetBg =[SKAction moveByX:backgroundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];


    SKAction *movebackgroundforever =[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[movBg,resetBg]]];
    for (int i= 0; i<2 + self.frame.size.width/(backgroundTexture.size.width*2 ); ++i) {
        SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];
        [sprite setScale:1.0];
        sprite.zPosition = -20; 
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(i* sprite.size.width, 0);
        [sprite runAction:movebackgroundforever];
        [_bgLayer addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: I think you need to multiply `_gameScore` directly into `_move`, and why are you multiplying `backgroundTexture.size.width`.

Comment: can u edit the code please how?

Comment: because its timeinterval with width to move horizontally

Comment: But you are passing that in duration parameter, here we only need to provide duration of animation/action.

Comment: yes im passing with duration parameter to move background which multiplies width everytime whatever i provide the time

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

it will directly multiply animation time with score with `_move*__gameScore` and you can also provide some intalize value to `_move` variable.

```
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"background10"];

NSTimeInterval _move;


SKAction *movBg = [SKAction moveByX:-backgroundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:_move*__gameScore]; 
SKAction *resetBg =[SKAction moveByX:backgroundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];


SKAction *movebackgroundforever =[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[movBg,resetBg]]];
for (int i= 0; i<2 + self.frame.size.width/(backgroundTexture.size.width*2 ); ++i) {
    SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];
    [sprite setScale:1.0];
    sprite.zPosition = -20; 
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(i* sprite.size.width, 0);
    [sprite runAction:movebackgroundforever];
    [_bgLayer addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: thats not correct because we need to multiply background with NSTimeInterval to move background but not with Int Value

Comment: if u multiply with _gamescore background won't move